# Opening a folder with a certain files forces a return to the parent folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-sbs-2011, windows-server-2019, mappeddrive

I have this unbelievable behaving in this constellation:

1. Windows Server 2019 Standard Desktop running in the trial version the 2nd day. A fresh copy, without additional software. Just added the server to the domain.
2. The drive `F:` is mapped to an existing SBS 2011 while the login process.
3. I can reproduce it with any user [e.q. Administrator and a normal one].

What is the issue? When I open a folder in one of these ways

1. Double click
2. Enter
3. Open in new window
4. Through "Quick Access"

then a folder with a certain content is displayed for less than a half second and then the parent directory [in this case the `\` directory] is shown again. In this animated GIF you see exactly what is going on.

To clarify: When I double click the directory `_1` then it opens for a very short time and then immediately the parent folder is shown again. This is **NOT** the GIF replay - that you understand it better. The short gray fading shows the end of the animation before it restarts.

[image]

After testing around I found out that it seems to be some certain files which cause this behaving. In this folder the 2 EXE files are responsible for this behaving. When I delete them and add other files into the directory then it behaves how it should and the directory remains open [the gray background is at the end of the animation before it starts to replay - so you understand the difference].

[image]

Accessing this directory from Windows Server 2012 R2 works as it should: The directory remains open.

What is the reason? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the Windows "Real Time Protection".

I disabled it in the "Local Group Policy Editor":

```
Computer Configuration > 
 Administrative Templates > 
  Windows Components > 
   Windows Defender Antivirus
```

[image]

**Please take into account that this may be a security risk!**

For the moment I don't have any other solution. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Especially, I would like to know what is exactly the problem with these files as they are language packs for Microsoft Office delivered by **Microsoft** which I find very ironical.